# How to send multiple files to controller of ASP.NET Core using Axios?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, axios, form-data

I have tried IFormCollection and tried to deserialization of JSON but nothing worked for me. I'm new to ASP.NET Core, React and Axios. I'm working on a feature where user can upload multiple files and can provide details of that event.

I have used following code.

```
uploadFiles() {
    var eventDate = moment(this.state.dateOfEvent).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    var eDate = Date.parse(eventDate)
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("Event_name", this.state.eventName);

    var imgArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.chosenImages.length; i++) {
        imgArr.push(this.state.chosenImages[i]);
    }

    var jsonImgs = JSON.stringify(imgArr);
    formData.append("Image_Path", jsonImgs);
    formData.append("Event_Date", eventDate);
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/Account/UploadGalleryImages',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: formData,
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.data.status == "SUCCESS") {
            confirmAlert({
                title: 'Gallery',
                message: response.data.message,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        label: 'Okay',
                        onClick: () => window.location.replace('/Reload_Window')
                    },
                ]
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log("Response:", response);
            confirmAlert({
                title: 'Window Title',
                message: response.data.message,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        label: 'Okay',
                    },
                ]
            });
        }
    }.bind(this))

}
```

React Code

```
<FormGroup>
<Input
    placeholder="Choose Image of Event"
    type="file"
    accept="image/jpeg,image/x-png"
    multiple="multiple"
    className="form-control"
    onChange={(event) => this.handleChosenImages(event.target.files) }
/>
```

```
handleChosenImages(chosenFiles) {
    this.setState({
        chosenImages: chosenFiles
    })
}
```

Request object for controller in ASP.NET Core

```
    public class GalleryImagesAddRequest
    {
        private string event_name;
        private string event_date;
        private IList<IFormFile> fileCollection;

        public string Event_name { get => event_name; set => event_name = value; }
        public IList<IFormFile> Image_Path { get => fileCollection; set => fileCollection = value; }
        public string Event_Date { get => event_date; set => event_date = value; }
    }
```

Controller Code for receiving all data.

```
        [HttpPost("UploadGalleryImages")]
        [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
        public string UploadGalleryImages(GalleryImagesAddRequest request)
        {
            Gallery gallery = new Gallery();
            EventDetail eventDetail = new EventDetail();
            Context db = new Context();
            string message = "";

            try
            {
                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(request.Event_Date).Date;
                eventDetail.event_name = request.Event_name;
                eventDetail.event_date = dateTime;
                db.EventDetail.Add(eventDetail);
                db.SaveChanges();

                message = "SUCCESS";
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                new Logger().write(ex);
                message = "failed";
            }

            return message;
        }
```

Please anyone tell me where I'm making mistake while trying to receive all images at server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to serialize files array, and secondly, in order to bind an array in `ASP.NET Core` you need to append multiple values with the same key to `FormData`. So change this part of code

```
var imgArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.chosenImages.length; i++) {
    imgArr.push(this.state.chosenImages[i]);
}

var jsonImgs = JSON.stringify(imgArr);
formData.append("Image_Path", jsonImgs);
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.chosenImages.length; i++) {
    formData.append("Image_Path", this.state.chosenImages[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It worked perfectly. After a long time and so many days, finally my controller received selected files. I wanna give more than one vote to this answer but I can't. Thank you so much @Alexander.